# How to return NULL instead of 0 from MySQL TinyInt(1)

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I've moved a site from ColdFusion 10 to ColdFusion 2016, and I've noticed when querying a MySql database, `tinyint(1)` fields that are `null` would previously come back to ColdFusion as empty values but now come back as `0`.

Anyone know if this is a MySql or CF2016 thing, and how I can get it to return empty values again?

I've googled, but all results seems to be about turning `0` into `null`. I need it the other way around! [CF2018 seems to have changed their null support](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/07/null-support-in-coldfusion-2018/), but I can't find anything relating to C2016.

Comment: Not really sure whether this is a CF thing or MySQL thing. But FWIW try checking the `ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib\neo-datasource.xml` file to see if the DSN connection string looks like this `<string>jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3310/trainer?tinyInt1isBit=false&amp;allowMultiQueries=true</string>` with `tinyInt1isBit` as `false`. Note: I am just talking out loud. Not sure if this has any impact in your case.

Comment: @rrk thanks, no it doesn't mention tinyint anywhere in that file

Comment: ColdFusion does not come with a MySQL driver. How did you connect CF10? How do you connecf CF2016?

Comment: @luke - Don't know what jdbc driver you are using, but... try adding it. According to the docs that setting is true by default but it sounds like you want it to be false https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Comment: ... but a lot depends on the jdbc driver you're using (and MySQL version), neither of which were mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @Ageax the versions are MySQL: 5.7.10 - JDBC Driver: 5.1.38

Comment: so i had hostek support take a look, but they said they couldn't solve it but could get their coldfusion team to take a look - but in doing what they did, it updated the neo-datasource.xml file and added two bits 1) <var name='args'><string>tinyInt1isBit=false</string></var> and 2 ) <var name='CONNECTIONPROPS'><struct><var name='tinyInt1isBit'><string>false</string></var></struct></var> - and now it works :) thanks @RRK i wouldn't even have known to look at that neo-datasource.xml file!

Comment: Everything you set in `neo-datasource.xml` can likel be set in the datasource settings in cfadmin.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler CF ships with MySQL drivers. If you choose to use the JDBC driver downloaded from MySQL.com, the settings differ a bit from what ships with it.

Comment: I go to `Data Sources` in cfadmin, select `MySQL 5` and get the message: `•The standalone MySQL JDBC driver is no longer shipped with ColdFusion.`
`Please download it, put it in cf_root/lib folder and restart ColdFusion.`. Adobe says: `All versions of Macromedia ColdFusion MX include a MySQL JDBC Type 4 driver. However, some users may choose to use more recent MySQL JDBC drivers`(https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-mx-configuring-mysql-jdbc.html). I didn't know that. Thanks for making that clear.

Comment: @luke can you post the `CREATE TABLE` definition for the one in question?

Comment: *"in doing what they did, it updated the neo-datasource.xml*" @luke - They probably updated the DSN in the CF Administrator. Whenever you successfully change a DSN, all of the settings are saved back to neo-datasource.xml (shouldn't need to update it manually).  Don't know what settings they changed, but if you're using the default MySQL DSN, you should be able to add the setting to the "Connection String" text box `tinyInt1isBit=false` OR for DSN type Other, add it to the jdbc URL:  `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databaseName?tinyInt1isBit=false`

Comment: @RRK - You or luke should write that up as an answer

Comment: @Ageax I have added an answer. I am not sure, how flexible the hostek control panel is in allowing connection strings. But I think there will be an option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL JDBC drivers, there is a property `tinyInt1isBit` which is set as `true` by [default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html#connector-j-reference-set-config) (When this is `true`, `tinyint(1)` field will be treated as `bit` field). This feature can be overridden by making a connection string modification by adding `tinyInt1isBit=false` to it.

`jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.140:3306/testdb?tinyInt1isBit=false`

But when we create a ColdFusion datasource, `tinyInt1isBit=false` will be added to the connection string by default(from my personal experience). This can be seen in the `ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib\neo-datasource.xml` file when we do a local installation.

I am not sure how hostek is handling getting rid of this from `neo-datasource.xml`. I believe you'll be creating or editing datasources from the hostek control panel. I don't remember if there is an option to enter connection string when you edit a DSN, but if there is field for that, then you can add `tinyInt1isBit=false` in there and that should fix your issue.